# Tomcat returning 403 - forbidden error

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

On apache-tomcat-7.0.55/ubuntu 12.04 behind apache2 mod ajk.

I am noticing a strange problem - tomcat is returning 403 status code for some files. This application is not under any kind authentication/authorization. As a matter of fact, this application is our static resources such as javascript/css and images.

As far as I can see in the logs tomcat randomly returns 403 when accessing fonts (.ttf, .woff files). If I copy the request from chrome (copy as curl) and try it using curl, I do get proper file back with 200, but in chrome it shows 403 error randomly. Copy as curl in chorme provides the headers that chrome had used to access the resoure. Any other files in the same application do not get 403 errors at all.

I have checked tomcat mime type and it looks ok. Its random (at least so far I don't know the reason) 403 that worries me as tomcat does serve the file sometimes and returns 403 other times.

Any ideas what can be happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I use ubuntu and apache2 and normally with 403 file permission errors coming my server/localhost it's because, while the files may have the correct permissions, the directories that the files are in may not, or vice-versa.

Usually in terminal I type `ls -l` to see the permissions and then `chmod 755 [file or directory]` to turn on read/execute permissions.